# Font family style only after elements visible in viewport

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm using a custom font and the font change on the heading inside a slider is only being applied after navigating to that slide.
Why is that happening?

Video is uploaded to Microsoft OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AjyQFn2ZJU2StJhee5oFvoEDivx60g?e=EKqd7q - this way it's easier to see the issue. The site is not publicly available.

Comment: Please add some code or a snippet, otherwise it is very hard to pinpoint the issue. Do you have the font locally or are you importing it from a link? Try adding a class like:     *{font-family: ‘yourfont’}

Comment: It's a Squarespace website and when the animations of the site are turned on this happens. When I turn off the animations the update is not visible

Comment: Then there might be a default font that transitions to yours, what you are seeing might be the animation, but again not sure not knowing what css there is behind

Comment: Try adding a transition-duration 0s and a transition-delay 0s on the element and add !important

Comment: @Skin_phil, I tried but the issue was that other elements were added in the `h2`. Added response

Answer (score 0):

The site is on Squarespace and when animations from the site were enabled this problem appear.

It seems that in the `<h2>` tag the animation was done by adding additional elements(2) inside the tag. Each tag contained a little part of the text and those elements were not targeted by the CSS code for the `font-family`.

This CSS fixed it:

```
.locals-guide-slider  h2,
.locals-guide-slider  h2 *,
.locals-guide-slider  h3,
.locals-guide-slider  h3 * {
    font-family: "neue-haas-grotesk-display",sans-serif !important;
}
```